# Editing a CSV file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, csv

I've created a gimp image that is 10x10 pixels:
[Image of my initials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpurO.jpg).

From this I then converted from ppm to csv by using Notepad++ (I've organized the numbers in 30 digits per column with 10 rows: [Image of my csv file opened with text editor in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojPOB.jpg)).

My task is to create some code into eclipse that will make the image less messy (meaning it will replace the commas with spaces, put a space after every three numbers, and create a new line after every 30 numbers).

The second part of the task is to work backwards. I would then need to convert the new organized created ppm file to .xcf to open my picture in gimp. It should be the same as the picture as the initials above.

The area where I need help is in eclipse.  What code would I need to write that would allow me to edit this .csv file in java format (I know this is a broad question but any tips or pointers would be so much appreciated)? Where would I put the csv file in eclipse (src, java project, etc). If you've bared with me this long then you have my full thanks. I tried to simplify my problem as much as possible so that it's understandable and solvable. I would appreciate any help as I need this done by monday. Thanks!

~Ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Java in Eclipse IDE,

1. For reading the file you can use import java.io.FileReader
2. For parsing the file line by line you can use BufferedReader or
   String []

Here is sample code for startup.

```
public class SplitterExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Input file which needs to be parsed
        String fileToParse = "SampleCSVFile.csv";
        BufferedReader fileReader = null;             

    //Delimiter used in CSV file
    final String DELIMITER = ",";
    try
    {
        String line = "";
        //Create the file reader
        fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToParse));

        //Read the file line by line
        while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            //Get all tokens available in line
            String[] tokens = line.split(DELIMITER);
            for(String token : tokens)
            {
                //Print all tokens
                System.out.println(token);
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally
    {
        try {
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks very much for your feedback! But I was able to finish the homework through trial and error using my professors guide. This is what I came up with: put the correct file name (csv one) into a File object and then edit it from there. Your post is also very helpful. Thanks!